# How to get Median string value from array with multiple strings in Python?

Tags: arrays, string, median

I have array, which holds values like for example 1's and 0's.
like this:

```
['00100','00101','00101','01100','01001','00101']
```

And I want to get median of each char in each string of array:

return would be something like this:

```
'00101'
```

If you can give example in Python it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has natural idioms for this sort of problem. The idea is to split things into nice digestible chunks of all the 0-th chars, all the 1-th chars, all the 2-th chars, ... etc. (the zip(*a) part); then figure out the median for each chunk (the sorted(d)[len(a)/2] part); and then to join those chunks back together again. That gives us the one-liner:

```
def findMedians(a):
    return ''.join(sorted(d)[len(a)/2] for d in zip(*a))

print findMedians(['00100','00101','00101','01100','01001','00101'])
# 00101
print findMedians(['1210', '2501', '1234'])
# 1211
```

If you find this a bit confusing, try:

```
print zip('123','456','789')
a = ['123','456','789']
print zip(*a)
```

to see what the '*' operator is doing here.

Answer (score 2):

So you have 2d array

```
array = {['1210'], ['2501'], ['1234']} // [3][4] array
```

I would create new 2d array that stores strings containing 0th char from each string of original array, 1st char, 2nd char,...

```
tempArray[4][3]

i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1){
        tempArray[i][j] = array[j][i]
    }
    // when outer cycle finishes collecting nth chars
    // you need to sort it from smallest to largest digit
    sortAscending(tempArray[i])
}
```

resulting array would look like this

```
// chars of   0th,      1st,     2nd,     3th    elements
tempArray = {['112'], ['225'], ['013'], ['014']}
```

Finally, you collect middle chars to new string

```
stringOfMedians[4];
for(i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1){
    // Take middle element from each string and put it in final string.
    stringOfMedians[i] = tempArray[i][strlen(tempArray[i])/2]
}
```

Final result

```
stringOfMedians = '1211'
```

One more remark. You should add

```
stringOfMedians[i] = tempArray[i][strlen(tempArray[i])/2]
```

to outer cycle of first code block I showed for optimization. It doesn't have to have its own cycle.
Final result:

```
array = {['1210'], ['2501'], ['1234']} // [3][4] array

tempArray[4][3]; 

i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1){
        tempArray[i][j] = array[j][i]
    }
    // when outer cycle finishes collecting nth chars
    // you need to sort it from smallest to largest digit
    sortAscending(tempArray[i]);

    // Take middle element from string and put it in final string.
    stringOfMedians[i] = tempArray[i][strlen(tempArray[i])/2]
}
```

Comment: Your solution is actually the same as mine; but Python has cool built-ins like zip, as well as list comprehension, which remove the need for explicit temporary variables like 'tempArray'.

Comment: @ChasBrown Both are good answers. I just like to keep it short. Joseph does do explain it little more though.

Comment: Indeed; wanted to give him kudos as well.